Uniswap OLD revert after swap
I am initializing new pool, and have a contract that allows doing swap on it utilizing TWAP Oracle. I have tested the TWAP and in tests it needed 1 second delay to return correct quotes, until doing a swap and quoting again. Then it throws OLD error. That was tested on Base fork. I deployed this contracts on sepolia base and I wasn't able to quote until secondsAgo for consult passed.
What I am missing:

how is it possible that in test on mainnet fork I was able to quote just after 1 sec?
why after doing swap I am getting out of observations?

My test file:
function test_quote_after_pool_init() public {
    uint160 sqrtPriceX96 = 250541448375047936131727360;
    address pool = PoolHelper.initPool(
        address(weth),
        address(token),
        uint24(3000),
        sqrtPriceX96,
        positionManager
    );

    // deal tokens
    deal(address(weth), address(this), 20 ether);
    deal(address(token), address(this), 10_000_000 ether);

    // approve tokens
    weth.approve(address(positionManager), 20 ether);
    token.approve(address(positionManager), 10_000_000 ether);

    PoolHelper.addLiquidity(
        IUniswapV3Pool(pool),
        20 ether,
        10_000_000 ether,
        address(this),
        positionManager
    );

    // TWAP needs some delay
    vm.warp(1 seconds);
    uint256 amountOut = quoter.quote(address(weth), 1 ether);
    console.log(amountOut);
}

My Quoter contract:
function quote(
    address tokenIn,
    uint256 amountIn
) external view returns (uint256 amountOut) {
    if (tokenIn == usdc) {
        uint256 usdc_to_weth = estimateAmountOut(
            tokenIn,
            weth,
            uint128(amountIn),
            500
        );
        return estimateAmountOut(weth, token, uint128(usdc_to_weth), 3000);
    }
    return estimateAmountOut(tokenIn, token, uint128(amountIn), 3000);
}

/// @dev Function to estimate the output amount based on TWAP
function estimateAmountOut(
    address tokenIn,
    address tokenOut,
    uint128 amountIn,
    uint24 fee
) internal view returns (uint256 amountOut) {
    address pool = IUniswapV3Factory(factory).getPool(
        tokenIn,
        tokenOut,
        fee
    );

    if (pool == address(0)) {
        revert InvalidPool();
    }

    (int24 tick, ) = OracleLibrary.consult(pool, SECONDS_AGO);
    amountOut = OracleLibrary.getQuoteAtTick(
        tick,
        amountIn,
        tokenIn,
        tokenOut
    );
}


The pool has a default value of cardinality as 1. I needed to changed that on
my pool with increaseObservationCardinalityNext(). But not sure how this works excatly.
https://uniswapv3book.com/milestone_5/price-oracle.html#increasing-cardinality
